# How do I open a 3rd window from the 2nd window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have the following elements in UI:

1. One main window
2. Two secondary windows

I want to be able to open the 3rd window from my second window. I already have 2 buttons on my 1st Main window that opens the 2nd and 3rd window, but I also want to add a button to my 2nd window that opens the 3rd one.

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs I have these 2 functions that I added and they work fine

```
private void BtnClickP_L(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Main.Content = new Patient_list();
}

private void BtnClickP_I(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Main.Content = new Patient_info();
}
```

But when I try to do the same in my Patient_list.xaml.cs file, I got an error when I try to say:

private void BtnClickM_i(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
MainWindow.Content = new Patient_info(); // error here CS0103 Main does not exists in current context
}

Also if I try to add it to my main file (MainWindow.xaml.cs) just like this:

```
private void BtnClickP_L(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            Main.Content = new Patient_list();
}

private void BtnClickP_I(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Main.Content = new Patient_info();
}

private void BtnClickM_i(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Main.Content = new Patient_info();
}
```

I have no error, I can run the program, but when clicking on it, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a MainWindow object first, Try to access your MainWindow like this in your Patient_list.cs:

```
    private void BtnClickM_i(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow MW = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        MW.Content = new Patient_info();
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. When I try what you suggested I get the following error message: CS1061  'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'BtnClickP_I' and no accessible extension method 'BtnClickP_I' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Is Btn a control you have on MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: Hello. Yes, BtnClickP_I is in MainWindow.xaml. This button takes me from the 1st page to the 3rd page. The button that I am interested to implement is called  BtnClickM_i. This button can be found on the 2nd page and it also has to take me to the 3rd page. BtnClickM_i can be found in Patient_list.xaml(2nd page). My 3rd page is called Patient_info.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to the `MainWindow` and set the `Content` of its `Main` element:

```
var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
window?.Main.Content = new Patient_info();
```